# Python 3 Extracting Candidate Words from a Debate File

Tags: python

This is my first post, so I'm sorry if I do anything wrong. That said, I searched for the question and found something similar that was never answered due to the OP not giving sufficient information. This is also homework, so I'm just looking for a hint. I really want to get this on my own.

I need to read in a debate file (.txt), and pull and store all of the lines that one candidate says to put in a word cloud. The file format is supposed to help, but I'm blanking on how to do this. The hint is that each time a new person speaks, their name followed by a colon is the first word in the first line. However, candidates' data can span multiple lines. I am supposed to store each person's lines separately. Here is a sample of the file:

> LEHRER: This debate and the next three -- two presidential, one vice
>   presidential -- are sponsored by the Commission on Presidential
>   Debates. Tonight's 90 minutes will be about domestic issues and will
>   follow a format designed by the commission. There will be six roughly
>   15-minute segments with two-minute answers for the first question,
>   then open discussion for the remainder of each segment.
>
> Gentlemen, welcome to you both. Let's start the economy, segment one,
>   and let's begin with jobs. What are the major differences between the
>   two of you about how you would go about creating new jobs?
>
> LEHRER: You have two minutes. Each of you have two minutes to start. A
>   coin toss has determined, Mr. President, you go first.
>
> OBAMA: Well, thank you very much, Jim, for this opportunity. I want to
>   thank Governor Romney and the University of Denver for your
>   hospitality.
>
> There are a lot of points I want to make tonight, but the most
>   important one is that 20 years ago I became the luckiest man on Earth
>   because Michelle Obama agreed to marry me.

This is what I have for a function so far:

```
def getCandidate(myFile):    
    file = open(myFile, "r")
    obama = []
    romney = []
    lehrer = []
    file = file.readlines()
```

I'm just not sure how to iterate through the data so that it separates each person's words correctly. I created a dummy file to create the word cloud, and I'm able to do that fine, so all I am wondering is how to extract the information I need.

Thank you! If there is more information I can offer please let me know. This is a beginning Python course.

EDIT: New code added from a response. This works to an extent, but only grabs the first line of each candidate's response, not their entire response. I need to write code that continues to store each line under that candidate until a new name is at the start of a line.

```
def getCandidate(myFile, candidate):   
    file = open(myFile, "r")
    OBAMA = []
    ROMNEY = []
    LEHRER = []
    file = file.readlines()
    for line in file:
        if line.startswith("OBAMA:"):
            OBAMA.append(line)
        if line.startswith("ROMNEY:"):
            ROMNEY.append(line)
        if line.startswith("LEHRER:"):
            LEHRER.append(line)
    if candidate == "OBAMA":
        return OBAMA
    if candidate == "ROMNEY":
        return ROMNEY
```

EDIT: I now have a new question. How can I generalize the file so that I can open any debate file between two people and a moderator? I am having a lot of trouble with this one.

I've been given a hint to look at the beginning of the line and see if the last word of each line to see if it ends in ":", but I'm still not sure how to do this. I tried splitting each line on spaces and then looking at the first item in the line, but that's as far as I've gotten.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! How is each candidate's words supposed to be stored (in the output file)?

Comment: Hello, thank you! They are not stored in an output file. They need to be stored in a list so that I can use the list to remove common words, find the top 40 words, and put them in a word cloud. I don't believe I am supposed to put them to an output file first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hint is this: after you split your lines, iterate over them and check with the string function **startswith** for each candidate, then append.

The iteration over a file is very simple:

```
for row in file:
    do_something_with_row
```

EDIT:
To keep putting the lines until you find a new candidate, you have to keep track with a variable of the last candidate seen and if you don't find any match at the beginning of the line, you stick with the same candidate as before.

```
if line.startswith('OBAMA'):
    last_seen=OBAMA
    OBAMA.append(line)
elif blah blah blah

else:
    last_seen.append(line)
```

By the way, I would change the definitio of the function: instead of take the name of the candidate and returning only his lines, it would be better to return a dictionary with the candidate name as keys and their lines as values, so you wouldn't need to parse the file more than once. When you will work with bigger file this could be a lifesaver.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the suggestion. I did that, however, it only grabbed the first line of each candidate's reponse. The problem is that when a candidate talks their responses cover multiple lines, and this doesn't account for all of the lines, only the ones that begin with their name. I will add the new code to my original post if you'd like to see! :)

Comment: For example, my code grabbed this: "OBAMA: Well, thank you very much, Jim, for this opportunity. I want to thank Governor Romney and the University of Denver for your hospitality." but it didn't grab this: "There are a lot of points I want to make tonight, but the most important one is that 20 years ago I became the luckiest man on Earth because Michelle Obama agreed to marry me."

Comment: Thank you so much! This has been bothering me for days. I really appreciate it. :) I would upvote your comment but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: glad to be useful, have fun learning python, it is well worth the effort!